Can .NET inputbox change based on its own checkboxes?
Im trying to make a custom inputbox based on a
Tutorial.
Everything is going great but I wonder if I can make the inputbox change based on checkboxes.
So if box "get file" is checked, a dropdown appears. If box "merge files" is checked, an extra field appears to add a name for the new, merged file.
I've tried:
if ($GetFileCheck.checked = $false){
    $form.Controls.Add($labelDrop)
    $Form.Controls.Add($DropDownBox)
}

But (obviously) this triggers once when the inputbox gets shown. What happends after that point doesnt change anything.
Is there a way to achieve this within one inputbox or should I make a second inputbox that shows all the options based on the checkboxes of the first inputbox?

You need to add an event listener to your checkbox.
Try this script.
$GetFileCheck.add_CheckedChanged({
    if ($GetFileCheck.checked) {
        $form.Controls.Remove($labelDrop)
        $form.Controls.Remove($dropDownBox)
    } else {
        $form.Controls.Add($labelDrop)
        $form.Controls.Add($dropDownBox)
    }
})


This question is about Powershell, not javascript

You can simplify this with e.g. $labelDrop.Visible = -not $GetFileCheck.Checked - no need to keep adding and removing controls…
